# Assistance with Javascript function, can not get prompt box to appear

Tags: javascript, slideshow

```
<script>
  var showCounter = 0 ;
  var myTimeout ; 
  function myShow( )
   {
   if (showCounter== 0) ;
   {
    document.mypic.src="one.jpg"
    showCounter =1
    }
    else if (showCounter==1) 
    {
        document.mypic.src="two.jpg"
        showCounter =2
        }
    else if (showCounter==2) ;
    {
        document.mypic.src="three.jpg"
        showCounter =3
        }
    else 
    {
        document.mypic.src="four.jpg"
        showCounter=0
    }
     myTimeout=setTimeout ("myshow ()", 1000)
     }
    </script>

<body>
<img src="one.jpg" 
    name="one"
    onclick="myShow()">
```

What is wrong with this function? I ran it through the debugger and can't get it to work.I also ran it through the other software to validate and it says the function works but it does not run the slideshow. Any  help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: @Juhana - well, looking at the code (almost) every single line is an error ?

Comment: Sure, but the point is to teach the OP to find them themselves.

Comment: Being a nice guy, I fixed them -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dy2bP/1/**, but I agree with Juhana, learn to debug.

Comment: Thank you @adeneo. I am studying for a course and was having a log of trouble with that. My professor did not add the semi colons after the alert boxes, that was my biggest issue! Sorry for being such a beginner, but I'm not sure what "debugging" is

Answer (score 1):

In general you would benefit from the following semantic techniques:

- Always make sure to have the proper close tags (or lack thereof)
- Double check things like brackets and semicolons when you think the code should work and doesn't
- As mentioned in an above comment, utilize the debuggers offered in many mainstream internet browsers (often reached via CTRL+SHIFT+I) to track down errors in code

  ```
  <script> 
      //were missing a semicolon after "counter"
      var counter;

      function evaluateAge()
      {   
          //were missing a semicolon after userAge
          var userAge;

          //had an unwanted space between 'user' and 'Age'
          //were missing a semicolon at the end of the line
          userAge = prompt ("Please enter your age", "");

          //unwanted space between 'user' and 'Age'
          //recommend formatting if-else as below to avoid confusion
          //always doublecheck brackets and semicolons too
          if (userAge >= 21){
              alert("You can drink");
          }else{
              alert("You can not drink");
          }
      }
  </script>
  ```

  ```
  <form>
      <!--for semantics just go with a button tag-->
      <button type="button" name="drink" id="drink">Evaluate Your Age</button>
  </form>

  <script>
      //avoid statements akin to "onclick" in the markup
      //maintain separation by applying this way:
      document.getElementById("drink").addEventListener("click",evaluateAge);

      //in general you'd be better to avoid these inline "script" tags
      //use an external js file instead
  </script>
  ```

Comment: <script>
  var showCounter = 0 ;
  var myTimeout ; 
  function myShow( )
   {
   if (showCounter== 0) ;
   {
    document.mypic.src="one.jpg"
 showCounter =1
 }
 else if (showCounter==1) 
 {
  document.mypic.src="two.jpg"
  showCounter =2
  }
 else if (showCounter==2) ;
 {
  document.mypic.src="three.jpg"
  showCounter =3
  }
 else 
 {
  document.mypic.src="four.jpg"
  showCounter=0
 }
  myTimeout=setTimeout ("myshow ()", 1000)
  }
 </script>
 
<body>
<img src="one.jpg" 
 name="one"
 onclick="myShow()">           What is wrong with this?

Comment: There are a lot of errors in that code there. My recommendation would be to run it in a web browser and use the debugger to try and fix it as mentioned in the above answer. I would also recommend sites like www.codeacademy.com where you can take a beginners course in javascript. Please select the green checkmark next to my answer also if I gave the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Missing " after you can not drink and a curly bracket is not the same as a normal bracket.

Answer (score -1):

```
function evaluateAge(){
    var userAge = prompt ("Please enter your age", "");
    if (userAge >=21){
        alert("You can drink");
    }else{
        alert("You can not drink");
    }
}
```